# SharePoint Foundation vs Cloudappsportal

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to use "https://www.cloudappsportal.com/" for my company to create new site as its free.

- Need your help to understand difference between SharePoint Foudation and
  https://www.cloudappsportal.com/.
- Also is it safe to use https://www.cloudappsportal.com/.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudappsportal is hosting company and giving you the free 1 site collection under their xxx.cloudsahreportal.com domain. You cannt use your own domain name and your options are very limited in terms of managing.

SharePoint foundation is free /lite version of the SharePoint Server. To setup SPF you need to setup farm and that required Hardware  & Software(Windows OS, SQL Server etc). You have to configure it, monitor it, Manage it and Patch it with updates. But you will get full control on the farm and create many site web apps /site collections. you setup your personal domain in it.

Cloudshare free and ready to use, no maintenance , no personal domain and you have to manage your site collections. I think Space is also limited.

SPF, cost you in terms of Hardware & Software, More responsibility in term of Managing/ Monitoring...But full Control on it.

also check this http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/